# Api Return base64 image string as direct response not as json response how to handle in androidStudio

Tags: java, android

[image]

Using `retrofit 2.0` in android my `Json` response is `base64 image` without `keyvalue`. How to get the `image`.

Comment: it's whole base64 data without extra data ??

Comment: yes i attached screenshot of response @kubersingh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use response body

```
 @GET
Call<ResponseBody> downloadUrl(@Header(Constants.AUTHORIZATION) String header, @Url String url);
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(ConfigContentsManager.getInstance().getReadTimeOut(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(ConfigContentsManager.getInstance().getConnectionTimeOut(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ServerManager.getInstance().getCmsUrl())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

    RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> request =null;

        request= retrofitInterface.downloadUrl("...","....");

    request.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: @Get method Im using please see the attached image

Comment: @SelvaKumarSK from above code you will get the rough idea about implementation, I am assuming that know how to initiate and set up retrofit

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your image from the response since it does not have a key, you need to use `.ResponseBody` from `okhhtp3`, inside the

```java
 @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

        }
```

Insert the code below:

```java
//your other code


Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body().byteStream());
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

//your other code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ScalarsConverterFactory as retrofit's converter factory,code snippet as following:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
.client(client)//client's type is OkHttpClient
.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).build();
```

//then you can get string as result by retrofit .convert string(encode by base64)to bitmap

```
byte[] imgData = new byte[0];
try {
   imgData = Base64.decode(data);
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
Bitmap b = ImageUtil.bytesToBitmap(imgData);
```

add ScalarsConverterFactory dependency by

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.4.0"
//here 2.4.0 is version code you can choose any version what you want to use
```

Comment: public static Retrofit getApiclient(){
        if (retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        } .       Im using this for build baseurl i retrofit

Comment: this case you can change GsonConverterFactory to ScalarsConverterFactory because your result's type is not json but string,right?

Answer (score 0):

to get the image you have to decode that base64 string .

you can get image using decode that base64 string like this:-

```
 byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64 string,Base64.DEFAULT);
 final Bitmap decodedByte = 
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

after that set bitmap image into your imageview

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```